# Multi-tenancy redirect issue on client-side nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13, nextjs-rewrites

I am working on multi-tenancy feature for our white label apps in NextJS.

Each white label app will have a subdomain for example (apple.abc.org, samsung.abc.org).
In the middleware, based on the subdomain I need to redirect it to a single page.

I am referring following example from vercel.
https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-middleware/hostname-rewrites

`/pages/index.js` (also the app) is already configured to render content based on a certain tenant.

Middleware redirect me to `/pages/_sites/[site]/index.tsx`
this is where I can fetch the data for the tenant specific config. (either on server side (recommended) or on client side and push it to `/pages/index.js` page).

The issue here is, the conflict between `/pages/_sites/[site]/index.tsx` and `/pages/index.js`

So when I try to push to '/' route, it doesn't gets redirected to `/pages/index.js` instead it remains on `/pages/_sites/[site]/index.tsx`